# How to convert a GeoSeries to a GeoDataFrame with Geopandas

Tags: python, convert, geopandas, geoseries

I'm new in GeoPandas and I try to create my first script.

I successfully opened a shapefile and made a union of all entity and an envelope.
As it said in GeoPandas doc, after these 2 geometric manipulations it returns GeoSeries.

But how can I convert my GeoSeries to a GeoDataFrame to finally export it to a shapefile ?

I try this on point shapefile but my GeoDataFrame is empty...

```
import sys
import geopandas as gpd

shp = (sys.argv[1])

gdf = gpd.read_file(shp)

union = gdf.unary_union

env = union.envelope

envgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

envgdf['geometry'] = env
envgdf.geometry.name

print("\nGeoDataFrame :\n", envgdf)
```

Returns :

```
GeoDataFrame :
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [geometry]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type of `env` here is a Shapely Polygon. In this line

```
envgdf['geometry'] = env
```

You're trying to assign a Polygon to a Geometry column. You can instead create a Geoseries from the Polygon and create a Geodataframe based on that. Here's the updated code:

```
import sys
import geopandas as gpd

shp = (sys.argv[1])

gdf = gpd.read_file(shp)

union = gdf.unary_union

env = union.envelope

# Replace these three lines:

#envgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
#envgdf['geometry'] = env
#envgdf.geometry.name

# With
envgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(env))

# Edit: Following Tim C's comment below, this line sets geometry for resulting geodataframe
envgdf = envgdf.rename(columns={0:'geometry'}).set_geometry('geometry')

print("\nGeoDataFrame :\n", envgdf)
```

Comment: It's ok ! envgdf is a geodataframe but without a true geometry column. When I try to export as a shapefile, python returns `AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.`Column with geometry is names 0...

Comment: Ok I found myself. `envgdf = envgdf.rename(columns={0:'geometry'}).set_geometry('geometry')` solves this issue.

Comment: @TimC. you should consider writing an answer from your comment above

Answer (score 22):

`GeoDataframe` now accepts a `geometry` keyword argument. Taking advantage of that, we can write

```
envgdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(env))
```

This automatically sets the `GeoSeries` as the geometry column.